# Probability that A succeeds is 1/3 , B succeeds is 1/5, what is the probability that A suceeds if at least 1 of them succeeds

Tags: probability

I have three cases:

- At least one succeeds, the probability of it being B?
- At most one succeeds, the probability of it being A?
- Exactly one succeeds, the probability of it being A?

It would be easy determining the probability of the first parts, if at least one then there are three possibilities so: $\frac{1}{15} + \frac{2}{15} +\frac{4}{15}$

But it's "guaranteed" that the first parts happen so the probability of it being B isn't $\frac{3}{15}$, a friend think it is  $\frac{2}{3}$ since there are two possibilities. But the probabilities aren't split in thirds so would it be $\frac{2}{3} * \frac{7}{15}$ ? ...

I'm confused

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ independent?  Can you write the question as a conditional probability?

Comment: Your question states find the *probability* but you're talking about *odds*. You haven't shown the inter conversion also. What exactly are you supposed to find?

Comment: To be found are $P(B\mid A\cup B)$, $P(A\mid A^{\complement}\cup B^{\complement})$ and $P(A\mid A\Delta B)$. Posed like this (independence still lacks, in spite of former comment) the problems cannot be solved.

Comment: The question in the title seems to be different from those asked in the body. In any case, $P(A|\mathrm{at\ least\ one\ succeeds}) = \frac 57$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at it this way.

---

**'At least one' case**

If at least one succeeds then we have 
\begin{align}
P(\text{at least one success})&=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B')+P(A'\cap B)\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}+\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{5}\\
&=\frac{7}{15}
\end{align}

Now **given** that this is true, the cases where the success is B are $A\cap B$ and $A'\cap B$ (which is in fact, just $B$).

So we have
\begin{align}
P(B\mid\text{at least one success})&=\frac{P(B\cap\text{at least one success})}{P(\text{at least one success})}\\
&=\frac{P(A\cap B)+P(A'\cap B)}{P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B')+P(A'\cap B)}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{5}+\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{5}}{\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}+\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{5}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{3}{15}}{\frac{7}{15}}\\
&=\frac{3}{7}
\end{align}

Now can you do the rest in a similar manner? I will put the full solution down below in a while.

---

**'At most one' case**

We have
\begin{align}
P(\text{at most one success})&=P(A'\cap B')+P(A\cap B')+P(A'\cap B)\\
&=\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}+\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{5}\\
&=\frac{14}{15}
\end{align}

Now **given** that this is true, the only case where the success is A is $A\cap B'$.

So we have
\begin{align}
P(A\mid\text{at most one success})&=\frac{P(A\cap\text{at most one success})}{P(\text{at most one success})}\\
&=\frac{P(A\cap B')}{P(A'\cap B')+P(A\cap B')+P(A'\cap B)}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}}{\frac{14}{15}}\\
&=\frac{2}{7}
\end{align}

---

**'Exactly one' case**

We have
\begin{align}
P(\text{exactly one success})&=P(A\cap B')+P(A'\cap B)\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}+\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{5}\\
&=\frac{6}{15}
\end{align}

Now **given** that this is true, the only case where the success is A is $A\cap B'$.

So we have
\begin{align}
P(A\mid\text{exactly one success})&=\frac{P(A\cap\text{exactly one success})}{P(\text{exactly one success})}\\
&=\frac{P(A\cap B')}{P(A\cap B')+P(A'\cap B)}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}}{\frac{6}{15}}\\
&=\frac{2}{3}
\end{align}

Comment: Yeah this made it really clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have four separate cases:

$P(A \land B) = \dfrac{1}{15}$

$P(A \land \lnot B) = \dfrac{4}{15}$

$P(\lnot A \land B) = \dfrac{2}{15}$

$P(\lnot A \land \lnot B) = \dfrac{8}{15}$

(this assumes A and B are independent).

To find the probability that B succeeds given that at least one of A or B succeeds, first find the probability that at least one succeeds - you have correctly calculated this:

$P(A \land B) + P(A \land \lnot B) + P(\lnot A \land B) = \dfrac{7}{15}$

Within this, the probability that B succeeds is $\dfrac{1}{5}$ which is $\dfrac{3}{15}$. Then divide one probability by the other:

$\dfrac{3}{15} \div \dfrac{7}{15} = \dfrac{3}{7}$

Comment: Thanks now I understand!